# Get recent files from folder box api

Tags: box-api

I need to get recent files using box API. There is a way to get recent files from a folder on box api? or get top 10 files order by modified at parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [User Events](https://docs.box.com/reference#get-events-for-a-user) API. This will provide you a list of events that have occurred in a user's Box account. You can limit the query to just those events that result in `changes` to the account, such as file additions/updates. Further filtering must be done client-side.